# Porting to Python 3: string/bytes formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am porting a program from Python 2 to Python 3. I am having difficulties dealing with % (interpolation) operator, when values are bytes.

Suppose we need to port this expression from Python 2: `'%s: %s\r\n' % (name, value)`.

`name` and `value` in the ported version of the program are of type `bytes`. The result should be of type `bytes` too. In Python 3 binary interpolation is only planned for Python 3.5 (PEP 460). So, not sure if I am correct, but there are only two ways to deal with this problem -- concatenation or string encoding/decoding where appropriate:

```py
>>> name = b'Host'
>>> value = b'example.com'
>>> # Decode bytes and encode resulting string.
>>> ('%s: %s\r\n' % (name.decode('ascii'), value.decode('ascii'))).encode('ascii')
b'Host: example.com\r\n'
>>> # ... or just use concatenation.
>>> name + b': ' + value + b'\r\n'
b'Host: example.com\r\n'
```

As for me, both of these solutions are a bit ugly. Is there some convention/recommendation about how to port string formatting, when values are `bytes`?

Note `2to3` tool shouldn't be used and the program should work under both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Have you tried using `format` string method instead? E.g. '{0}: {1}\r\n'.format(name, value)`

Comment: objects of type `bytes` don't have `format` method. So you still need always to encode/decode.

Comment: `'{0}: {1}\r\n'` is not a bytes, isn't it?

Comment: @J0HN But that won't produce the desired output either, e.g. `str(name)` will be `"b'Host'"`.

Comment: I wasn't sure, that's why it was a comment, not answer.

Answer (score 2):

For CPython I made the [`bttf`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bttf) library, that I will add some porting features; currently it supports monkeypatching the 3.5 bytes formatting code into Python 3.3 ad 3.4:

Thus, before you'd have:

```
>>> b'I am bytes format: %s, %08d' % (b'asdf', 42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'tuple'
```

and with `bttf`:

```
>>> from bttf import install
>>> install('bytes_mod')
>>> b'I am bytes format: %s, %08d' % (b'asdf', 42)
b'I am bytes format: asdf, 00000042'
```

---

Unlike `__future__`s, the patching is interpreter-wide.

Answer (score 1):

The decoding-formatting-encoding solution may seem ugly in this particular case, but it is apparently idiomatic.

The idea is that you only operate on Unicode strings internally, and do decoding/encoding when receiving/sending data.
The approach is referred to as "Unicode sandwich" in [Ned Batchelder's "Pragmatic Unicode"](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#35).

Also, depending on the context, you might want to just change the fact that `name` and `value` are `bytes` objects.